# PERC H730 or H330

Tags: dell-perc

Would you get any any benefits going with the more expensive H730 vs H330?
We are planning SSDs only. Would the 1 GB Write cache do any good in this case? Other than that the only difference I see is the H730 is supporting raid6 and 60 while H330 is only good for Raid5 or 50.

Comment: This is strictly anecdotal, but my one and only experience with the H330 was abysmal. The performance was atrocious. - https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln164091/perc-performance-concerns-for-raid-controllers-without-cache-h330-h310-s130-s110-s300-s100-h200-sas-6-ir-sas-5-ir-?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

Check the specs. The Dell PERC H730 has different write and read policies which can improve the performance for particular patterns (Write-Back/Write-Through) while the Dell PERC H330 does have the only Write-Through policy without NVRAM caching.

https://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-PowerEdge-RAID-Controller-H730.pdf

https://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-PowerEdge-RAID-Controller-H330.pdf

Comment: Thank you, but my question was if I would see any benefits of using the 730 with a 1 gig cache and battery in situation when I would have a raid array built with SSDs